# Laravel getting an item from a table

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to Laravel and my question should be simple.
I have a table called LoanBook and it has a column called bookid.
so I have a where clause getting a record from the table and putting it into `$loanedbook`and then I am trying to get the bookid from this table from this line:

`$bookid = $loanedbooks->bookid;`

I get back the error that it's an undefined property, am I missing something?

edit: code with result

> $loanedbooks = LoanBook::where(function ($query) {
>             $query->where('userid', '=', 
>                     1);})->get();

Comment: show the code where you get the result from db

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling the `get` method which is necessary to actually retrieve the records from the database. Also, call `first` if you just want to retrieve 1 record.

Comment: sorry, edited to show end of line ->get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$loanedbooks = LoanBook::where(function ($query) { $query->where('userid', '=', 1);})->get();

This code will return an array of all rows that fulfill your where condition.So if you want to get the bookid then you need to use a loop like

```
foreach($loanedbooks as $lb){
   echo $lb->bookid;
}
```

better way is to change your query to get one row..

```
$loanedbook = LoanBook::where('userid', 1)->first();
```

or

```
$loanedbook = LoanBook::where('userid', 1)->take(1)->get();
```

You should try to learn debugging.Don't change your code and just print your variable to see the returns from the query.Then you will understand the actual reason of your problem..

```
$loanedbooks = LoanBook::where(function ($query) { $query->where('userid', '=', 1);})->get();
print_r($loanedbooks);exit();
```

or

```
$loanedbooks = LoanBook::where(function ($query) { $query->where('userid', '=', 1);})->get();
dd($loanedbooks);//laravel debugging system
```

Answer (score 1):

Select from table Loanbook in `$loanedbook`

Then

```
  foreach($loanedbook as $l_book)
                $bookid = $l_book->bookid;
    ----- Do Something
End foreach
```

Comment: hi Piyush, loanedbooks actually holds one record and i just need the value from the column bookid

Comment: @HammockKing although it hold one record... Is it an array or structure??
If it's an array (even if it holds one record).. we have to loop on it :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one record you could just do the following, because all Query Builder functions are available to use with Eloquent.

```
LoanBook::where('userid', 1)->first();
```

Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$loanedbook = LoanBook::where('userid', 1)->first();
$bookId = $loanedbook->bookid;
```

If you use this:

```
$loanedbooks = LoanBook::where('userid', 1)->get();
```

Then you have to loop through all the model collections because `get()` will return a collection of multiple `LoanBook` odels who has `userid=1` and if there is only one model available then it;ll return one model in the collection so to get the first item from the collection you may use:

```
$loanedbooks = LoanBook::where('userid', 1)->get();
$loanedbooks->first()->bookid; // get first item and then bookid
```

Or:

```
$loanedbooks = LoanBook::where('userid', 1)->get();
$loanedbooks->get(0)->bookid; // get first item and then bookid
$loanedbooks->get(1)->bookid; // get second item and then bookid
```

Or use a loop:

```
foreach($loanedbooks as $loanedbook) {
    $bookid = $loanedbook->bookid;
}
```